# Browser extension security: Content scripts with UI elements

Tags: security, browser-extension

I would like my browser extension to show an UI element in a web page, an info box, that sticks to the upper left corner.

I thought about implementing it with a floating `div` element, that is created by the content script when it is injected into a web page.

I wonder if there are any security considerations regarding a malicious webpage that tries to exploit the extension. I cant think of any, since the webpage does not have access to the content script's webext API and therefore also cannot access the background script under any circumstance. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: It can't access the webext API or modify the background script itself but they can manipulate the page's DOM just the same. If your script spawns a `div` there could be code on the target page that modifies that `div`. [Content Scripts - Communication with the embedding page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication)

Comment: @esqew Found an interesting resource: [extensionworkshop.com ](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/build-a-secure-extension/). _If the standard UI components aren’t sufficient for your needs use iframes with data URLs to prevent fingerprinting, or add iframes to the extension code so a page can’t interact with your UI content, such as buttons._